# Control opening screen position and size with MPlayer?

Tags: 16.04, video, configuration, mplayer

I am using the Repository version of the command line player MPlayer under Xenial Xerus LTS. When I open a video I would like to control the following:

1. The size of the MPlayer window
2. The position in the screen that the MPlayer window opens up in (i.e. centre, left, right. top etc)

How do I do this from the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two different sets of options that can be combined for ultimate output control:

**1. Window Size:**

The easiest way to set a size for the MPlayer window is to use the `-xy` option. If the value of this option is greater than 8 the width of the video window is set to that value. The height is then calculated from this width to maintain the correct aspect ratio.

To have a window 800 wide you would use the following:

```
mplayer -xy 800 test.mp4
```

**2. Screen Position:**

This can be set using the MPlayer `-geometry` option utilising either:

1. x and y coordinates:

   ```
   50:40 Places the window at x=50, y=40
   ```
2. Percentage values:

   ```
   50%:50% Places the window in the middle of the screen
   ```

To run a video in the *middle* of the screen try the following:

```
mplayer -geometry 50%:50% test.mp4
```

**3. All together now...**

Finally, to run the movie in the center of the screen, using a window width of 800, use the following:

```
mplayer -xy 800 -geometry 50%:50% test.mp4
```

How cool is the command line :)